# Regex on name still accept numbers

Tags: java, android, regex, validation

```
    boolean valid = true;

   if (Lnamee.isEmpty() || Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$").matcher(Lnamee).matches()) {
        Lname.setError("Enter letters only!");

        valid = false;
    }

    if (Mnamee.isEmpty() || Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$").matcher(Mnamee).matches()) {
       Mname.setError("Enter letters only!");
        valid = false;
    }

    if (Fnamee.isEmpty() || Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$").matcher(Fnamee).matches()) {
       Fname.setError("Enter letters only!");
        valid = false;
    }

   if (Emails.isEmpty() || Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]" + "\\@" + "[a-zA-Z]" + "\\." +  "[a-zA-Z]").matcher(Emails).matches()){
        Email.setError("Enter valid e-mail address!");
        valid = false;
    }

    if (Passwords.isEmpty() || Passwords.length() < 8){
       Password.setError("Password must be 8 characters!");
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
```

The regex pattern for the names still accepts number which should not be. Is there some problems with the validation patterns? I tried searching for others possible, but still it accepts numbers.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to write "if (name empty || regex does NOT match)"?

Comment: You should read https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ especially point #16

Answer (score 0):

All your if clauses are missing the negations.

I think you if statements should have the ! on the regex call.

```
if (Lnamee.isEmpty() || ! Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$").matcher(Lnamee).matches()) {
```

Comment: using the ! before the pattern.compile still accepts numbers

Comment: Are you sure that it is not working? For me the pattern is working. What is the input you are giving?

Comment: on the name, I tried entering: User1 but still it accepts the user input

Comment: I can confirm that running `System.out.println(Lnamee.isEmpty() || ! Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$").matcher(Lnamee).matches());` with Lnamee set to `User1` will output true. while `User` will output false.

Comment: In my machine it is not accepting numbers.                                     public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name ="User9";
        if (name.isEmpty() || Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$").matcher(name).matches()) {
            System.out.println("Ok!");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Enter letters only!");
        }
    }

Comment: @JohnathonHavens Yes. Im having problems and I cant find the reason why. Since I have the correct regex

Comment: @Jacky Perhaps do a `System.out.println(Lnamee);` before the if statement and see if it's being populated, it may be empty for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

your code is working. it does not accept numbers

if (Lnamee.isEmpty() || Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$").matcher(Lnamee).matches()) {
        Lname.setError("Enter letters only!");

```
    valid = false;
}
```